# Using element.triggerHandler() in angularjs tests for paste and keypress events doesn't seem to have an effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

Wondering if someone out there can shed some light on how to properly use `element.triggerHandler()` for the `paste` and `keypress` events inside of an angularjs unit test.

I have two directives, one for limiting the ability of a user to continue firing `keypress` events in an element once a length limit has been reached. The second is to prevent the user from pasting text into an element if the length of the text would exceed a limit.

See the following plunker for a full example including my failing tests: https://plnkr.co/edit/5Yyv2cnn3dRKzsj2Lj61?p=preview

For the `paste` test I know I'm not using the correct syntax but have been unable to find how to properly do this. Any suggestions?

`element.triggerHandler('paste', 'astring')`

For the `keypress` test, I believe I'm firing the event correctly but it doesn't seem to be updating the value of the element (retrieved using `element.val()`)

Been stuck on this for a bit, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are not getting the value in element.val(), please update the value of the element as 

    var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    element[0].value = value;

Comment: Hm, thanks for the response @Ajaykumar but I'm not sure that I follow. Can you provide a code sample or fork the plunker to illustrate what you mean? I'm trying to retrieve the value of the element after the event has been fired, not assign it to the element. `element[0].value` unfortunately returns the same empty string as `element.val()` was.

Comment: Still need help with this?

Comment: @tasseKatt Absolutely do, if you have any advice or resources that outline how this works I would love to get your input. Ended up punting for the time being and have a backlog task to address, would be great to close it out.

Comment: Will write an answer in an hour or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's us start with a short breakdown of what might happen (*really up to the browser implementation*) when a user presses and releases the `1` key with the focus on an input:

1. Event `keydown` is fired
2. Event `keypress` is fired
3. Value of input is changed to `1` and event `input` is fired
4. Event `keyup` is fired

There is no way in JS to actually simulate a user pressing a key. What you can simulate are the things that (usually) happen when a user does so, for example the steps above.

The `triggerHandler` function executes all handlers bound with jQuery for the specified event type on the specific element.

So using `triggerHandler` with `keypress` will not simulate a user pressing a key, it will only fire the event, like step 2 above. The value will not be changed, since that happens in another step.

Now, one would think that in your tests for the `limitKeypressLength` directive, you can simply simulate the first part of step 3 above yourself (just setting the value manually):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
  element.triggerHandler({type: 'keypress', keyCode: 49});
  element.val(element.val() + '1');
}

expect(element.val()).toBe('1111111111');

element.triggerHandler('keypress', {which: 49});
element.val(element.val() + '1');

expect(element.val()).toBe('1111111111');
```

This will not work however, since even if the eleventh keypress event is caught in your directive, the code below will still execute and update the value.

The basic functionality of the `limitKeypressLength` directive is to listen on the keypress event and either call `event.preventDefault` or not based. This is what you want to test.

For example:

```
// Set value to something longer than allowed
element.val('123456789123456789');

// Create the event
var e = jQuery.Event('keypress', {
  keyCode: 49
});

// Create a spy
spyOn(e, 'preventDefault');

// preventDefault should not have been called yet
expect(e.preventDefault).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

// Trigger the event
element.triggerHandler(e);

// Assert that preventDefault has been called
expect(e.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/ktmcBGSuTdMnvqVRlkeQ?p=preview

Now you can as easily test for when the elements value is set to equal/below the allowed value.

Basically the same goes for the `limitPasteLength` directive, since its purpose is also to call `preventDefault` based on a condition, only that there is some additional mocking to do.

Comment: @ZaneMattingly If you run into any problems writing the tests or just need guidance, just let me know.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot of sense and I think you're right on taking a different tact for testing. Great explanation and thanks for the working demo, you da man! :D

I'm still curious how `element.triggerHandler()` works with the 'paste' event. Never found any documentation on it. Is that simply not supported for simulating paste events and if it is supported how do you supply the data to be pasted?

Comment: Triggering the `paste` event simply fires all the listeners for that event, just like with `keypress`. It does not populate any clipboard data. You need to populate the event or window yourself according to how the specific browsers expect it to look.

Comment: Ah ha, was totally going at it the wrong way. Thanks, appreciate it.